# Question about an extension of Intuitionistic Logic

Tags: logic, intuitionistic-logic

Kurt Gödel introduced a mapping from Intuitionism to Classical S4 Modal Logic as follows:

$A’=\Box A$ where $A$ is a positive atomic formula.

$(\sim A)’=\Box \sim (A’)$

$(A \land B)’=A’ \land B’$

$(A \lor B)’=A’ \lor B’$

$(A \implies B)’=\Box (A’ \implies B’)$

By adding the following:

$(\neg A)’=\sim \Box (A’)$,

one obtains a propositional logic that roughly accounts for distinct negations, namely “impossibility” and “unnecessity” respectively.

Further, it is known that Intuitionistic Logic is equivalent to Heyting Algebra, Simply-Typed Lambda Calculus, and other mathematical structures/systems. Are there mathematical structures/systems that already correspond to this logic, and what might it take to transform e.g., Heyting Algebra into an algebra sufficient for this logic?

Note that though this logic is a naive extension of Intuitionism, it is non-constructive since the Law of the Excluded Middle is provable for the new negation operator.

Comment: You have asked 10 questions on this website. Even though seven of them have received answers, you have yet to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) any of them by clicking the check-mark. While you have no obligation to accept any particular answer, accepting one indicates to the wider community that your question has been settled and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. People will be more motivated to engage with your future questions if they can anticipate that you will eventually accept an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You notice that for any propositional formula in the logical language $(\wedge, \vee, \rightarrow, \sim)$ (where $\sim$ denotes the usual negation), we have $\vdash_{IPC} \varphi$ precisely if $\vdash_{S4} \varphi'$.

By analogy, you consider a logical system $p$, defined in such a way that for any propositional formula $\varphi$ in the extended logical language $(\wedge, \vee, \rightarrow, \sim, \neg)$, we have  $\vdash_p \varphi$ precisely if $\vdash_{S4} \varphi'$.

**You claim that the system $p$ constitutes "a naive extension of" intuitionistic logic. As we shall see, this claim fails, and no reasonable algebraic structure or system can correspond to $p$. In particular, it's not possible to extend the variety of Heyting algebras into a semantics for $p$.**

---

**I. Why is your system not an extension of intuitionistic propositional logic $IPC$?** Given any propositional formulas $\varphi, \psi$ of intuitionistic logic, we always have $\vdash_{IPC} (\varphi \rightarrow \:\sim\!\psi) \rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow \:\sim\!\varphi)$. However, we don't have $\vdash_p (\varphi \rightarrow\:\sim\!\psi) \rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow \:\sim\!\varphi)$.

Set $\varphi$ to the atomic formula $A$, and $\psi$ to the formula $\neg A$. Applying the $'$-translation to the resulting $p$-formula $ (A \rightarrow \:\sim\!\neg A) \rightarrow (\neg A \rightarrow \:\sim\! A)$
gives us the $S4$-formula
$$\Box (\Box (\Box A \rightarrow \Box (\sim \sim\! \Box \Box A)) \rightarrow \Box (\sim\! \Box \Box A \rightarrow \Box \!\sim\! \Box A))$$
which one *cannot* actually prove in $S4$! It fails because generally $\sim\!\Box x$ does not imply $\Box \!\sim\! \Box x$.

This means that, unlike intuitionistic logic, the system $p$ does not enjoy closure under substitution: from $\vdash_p \varphi$ you cannot conclude $\vdash_p \varphi[A := \psi]$.

The lack of closure under substitution makes the system $p$ extremely ill-behaved: in particular, it rules out the existence of any sort of sound/complete algebraic semantics for $p$.

---

**II. What happens if we try to fix the bad behavior by taking the "closure" $q$ of system $p$ under variable substitution?** We can do this, but we get something really boring: classical propositional logic. I will show this using a model-theoretic argument, but with a little effort one can turn the argument below into a direct $q$-proof of excluded middle for ordinary negation.

As you noted, your system has $\vdash_p A \vee \neg A$, so the closed system has $\vdash_q \varphi \vee \neg \varphi$ for all $\varphi$.

Moreover, I claim that $\vdash_p \sim\!\neg P \rightarrow P$ also holds, since the $'$-translation gives

$$(\sim\!\neg P)' = \Box \sim (\neg P)' = \Box\sim \sim \Box P' = \Box\!\sim \sim\!\Box \Box P$$

and consequently

$$(\sim\!\neg P \rightarrow P)' = \Box ((\sim\!\neg P)' \rightarrow P') = \Box (\Box\!\sim \sim\!\Box \Box P \rightarrow \Box P) $$

as well. Now, one can establish $\vdash_{S4} \Box (\Box\!\sim \sim\!\Box \Box P \rightarrow \Box P)$ e.g. by using the necessitation rule, then applying double-negation elimination to get rid of $\sim\sim$, and using the fact that $\Box = \Box\Box$ in S4. A nigh-identical argument gives $\vdash_p P \rightarrow \sim\!\neg P$ as well. It follows that $\vdash_q \varphi \leftrightarrow \sim\!\neg \varphi$ for all $q$-formulas $\varphi$.

Consequently, a model of $q$ would have to be a Heyting algebra $H$ equipped with a unary operator $\neg$ satisfying both $x \vee \neg x = \top$ and $\neg x \rightarrow \bot = x$ for all $x \in H$. I now show that all such Heyting algebras are Boolean algebras.

It suffices to show that $\neg x = x \rightarrow \bot$, since at that point $x \vee \neg x = \top$ will imply excluded middle.

First we show that $\neg x \leq x \rightarrow \bot$ by proving $\neg x \rightarrow (x \rightarrow \bot) = \top$. We can prove this as follows: $\neg x \rightarrow (x \rightarrow \bot) = x \rightarrow (\neg x \rightarrow \bot) = x \rightarrow x = \top$.

For the other direction $y \rightarrow \bot \leq \neg y$, notice that we already know $\neg x \leq x \rightarrow \bot$, so we can set $x = \neg y$ to conclude $\neg\neg y \leq \neg y \rightarrow \bot = y$. But if $\neg \neg y \leq y$, then by negating the inequality $y \rightarrow \bot \leq \neg\neg y \rightarrow \bot = \neg y$. Both inequalities hold, so we get that $y \rightarrow \bot = \neg y$ as claimed. Therefore, all models of $q$ are Boolean algebras.

---

**III. How did I know in advance that your system was going to be ill-behaved?** Well, generally, Heyting algebras describe how the *open subsets* of a topological space behave under the finitary operations of intersection, union, and "interior of the complement". The algebras corresponding to modal logic $S4$, so-called [interior algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_algebra), describe how *all subsets* of a topological space behave under the finitary operations of intersection, union, complement, and interior.

An open subset of a topological space is precisely a subset that coincides with its own interior. This is what makes Gödel's translation work: we simply treat the variables of intuitionistic logic as variables ranging over open sets inside the algebra of all sets.

Your attempted translation of the new operation $\neg$ breaks with this nice correspondence: it insists on translating $A$ as the complement ($\sim$) of an open set ($\Box$). But unfortunately, the complement of an open set is very rarely open! It would have required a remarkable coincidence to get something that respects substitution out of this.

After making this observation, all I had to do was look for a bad substitution instance. Once I had the substitution instance in hand, it quickly led me to the proof of Part II as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have been studying this logic for a few months, and have anticipated some of what you told me. I believe I have a sound and complete axiomatization for this logic, which you can see here  https://www.reddit.com/r/logic/comments/10qy9d8/an_axiomatic_system_for_an_extension_of/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=iossmf

Comment: Also, while not every Intuitionistic validity is a validity of system P, every theorem of Intuitionism is a theorem of P.

Comment: I hate to ask this months later, but hear me out. I understand that in algebras for modal logic $\Diamond$ is interpreted as closure. Why can’t $\neg$ be interpreted as the “closure of the complement”? I’m not well-versed in even Boolean Algebra, so forgive me if that’s a dumb question.

Comment: In the standard topological semantics of S4, $\sim$ is interpreted plainly as complement, and $\box$ is interpreted as interior. So as long as your $\neg$ is defined to mean the same thing as $\sim \box$, it will denote the complement of the interior, which *is* the same as the closure of the complement. The problem here is that the closure will be a closed set, and (in most topological spaces) most closed sets are not open. In particular, when ∼□x is not open, then the interior □∼□x is strictly smaller than ∼□x, so ∼□x does not imply □∼□x. This is the issue in Part I above.

Comment: What does this mean in terms of providing a Heyting-style semantics for this logic? It is actually one of the most important parts of this logic that we don’t have $\neg p \to \sim p$, so I’m not sure I’m seeing why the interior being strictly smaller is a bad thing. I understand that substitution is not possible for this logic in a lot of cases, but I don’t see why there can’t be a semantics that can determine the validity of *any* specific formula, as opposed to an arbitrary one. Thanks for your help and explanations, by the way.

Comment: An algebraic semantics interprets connectives as operations in some algebraic structure, and formulas as equations in that algebraic structure, and reduces provability in the logic to truth of the corresponding equation in all algebraic structures of a certain kind (e.g. Heyting algebras for intuitionisitc logic). A logic that does not satisfy substitution cannot have an algebraic semantics simply because variable substitution is always allowed in algebra. If $f(x) = g(x)$ in some algebraic structure for some variable $x$, then $f(k)=g(k)$ for any value or expression $k$.

Comment: This does not prevent you from having *some* semantics for your logic (in a sense, your translation to S4 induces a semantics) but it won't be an algebraic semantics.